# Is it possible to run IE11 emulation with protractor?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, testing, protractor

I would like to test my view also on ie10. However, I have ie11 on my machine. Is there a way to configure protractor so that I can run protractor using IE11 emulation to test IE10?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would actually think about using services like [BrowserStack](http://browserstack.com/) or [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/). They provide you with a huge variety of platforms and browsers to run your tests on. It's as easy as, for instance, in case of BrowserStack:

```
capabilities: {
    "browserstack.user": browserstackUser,
    "browserstack.key": browserstackKey,
    "browserstack.local": "true",
    "browserstack.debug": "true",

    browserName: "Internet Explorer",
    browser_version: 10,
    os: "Windows",
    os_version: "8",

    specs: [
        "specs/*.spec.js",
    ]
},
```